# Working with blocks in PiranhaCMS

Tags: piranha-cms

I am attempting to work with PiranhaCMS in ASP.NET MVC and I see a concept of "blocks."

However I don't see how to consume those blocks to show them on other areas.  How can I utilize blocks to form small content sections that have the same structure, but are not full pages.

Answer (score 1):

In Piranha CMS, blocks are just parts of a page, a way to easily build a composite page or SPA. Blocks are not reusable pieces of content that is stored in a content bank somewhere.

In fact, a block is just a sub page with a special flag that can't be navigated to directly. Blocks are loaded into the parent page model automatically and can be consumed with the Blocks property.

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Just so I can figure out, what do you mean by "blocks property?"

Comment: In looking more I see that blocks look a whole lot like pages.  What do you mean by can't navigate directly to them, I seem to be able to based on what I've done.

Comment: https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/blob/master/Core/Piranha/Models/PageModel.cs#L58

Yes, as I wrote previously a block is just a page located below another page with a special flag that is automatically included into the PageModel of its parent page.